# 'nvstrings' object has no attribute 'to_gpu_array'

Tags: rapids, cudf

I'm using cuML for stochastic gradient descent. I used sklearn's train_test_split to generate the splits for train_X, train_y ... from a cuDF dataframe.

The following code (I removed the hyperparameters which aren't relevant to this question):

```
from cuml.solvers import SGD as cumlSGD
cu_sgd = cumlSGD(eta0=0.005)
cu_sgd.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

Throws the following error on the cu_sgd.fit line:
'nvstrings' object has no attribute 'to_gpu_array'

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to first convert any column in `train_X` or `train_Y` that have the `string` `dtype` to `category` dtype. Strings can't be converted with `to_gpu_array` because they are not fixed-width. You'll lose the actual string values, but they can be reconstructed, and `cu_sgd.fit` should work fine.